# How can i add new ascx page to the dotnetnuke module?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I want to create a webservice to my module . Mainly there are three pages in dot netnuke module . 1)edit 2) setting 3)view pages . how can i add one more page to the dotnenuke module saying webservice . i wan to get this page in manage button as edit and setting page comes .

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional ASCX files to your project, but you then need to "Register" them with DotNetNuke, you can do this manually via the module definition on the HOST EXTENSIONS page, or you can update the .DNN manifest file to include the new ASCX registration.

To link to them using the MANAGE button (actions menu) you need to add a new ACTION item calling the URL to that ASCX file.